# PHP MySQL IF .. ELSE (Else Not Displaying Anything)

Tags: php

I am trying to go through all the records in a table and display something for all the records which has a match on the SQL and display something else for the record that don't have a match.

So I'm doing this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id='$my_id' ");

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {


      if (!empty($row['id'])) {

        echo 'Match Exists!';

      } else {

        echo 'There is NO Match';

      }



  }
```

My problem is that there is No echo for the non matches although there is for the matches.

So, I'm getting "Match Exists!" for the matches but no "There is NO Match" for the non matches.

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: For No Matches, it won't enter into the while loop itself as the query gets only the matching entries.

Comment: I understand your point but I when I need to add one or the other and if I add an echo outside the loop it's going to appear on both cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this

 <?php
    $result = mysql_query($con,"SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id='$my_id' ");
    $num=mysql_num_rows($result);

       if ($num!=0) 
       {

            echo 'Match Exists!';

          } else {

            echo 'There is NO Match';

          }
          ?>

                                OR




                                <?php
        $result = mysql_query($con,"SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id='$my_id' ");

      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
      {
    $id=$row['id'];
    $query=$result = mysql_query($con,"SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id='$id' ");
    $num=mysql_num_rows($query);
          if ($num!=0) 
          {
    echo 'Match Exists!';

          } else {

            echo 'There is NO Match';

          }
     } 

      ?>
```

Comment: While this seems to adress OP's requirement, it would be nice to describe what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id='$my_id

here you are checking if there exists any row where the ids matches so your code below loses his property:

```
if(!empty($row['id'])) {

        echo 'Match Exists!';

      } else {

        echo 'There is NO Match';

      }
```

You are already verifing if exists so there will not be any empty id.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no matches, `$row` will evaluate to `FALSE` (because no rows are returned). If you have to do it with a `while` loop, try `do { ... } while (...);`, like below.

The difference is that the `while()` condition is checked after the first iteration.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id='$my_id' ");

  do {
     $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
     if (!empty($row['id'])) {
       echo 'Match Exists!';
     } else {
       echo 'There is NO Match';
     }
  } while(!empty($row['id']));
```

Comment: I'm tried this and I'm getting "Match Exists!There is NO Match" together

Comment: I updated my answer (changed where condition) - try again and tell me how it went. It should execute only once if there are no matching rows .

Comment: Better but there's still a small bug. On the records that have a match I'm getting "Match Exists!There is NO Match" and on the ones that do not have a match "There is NO Match" //Last one is perfect but the ones with a match are displaying both

Comment: This is just **impossible**, as `if() {} else {}` statement **guarantees** only one of them is executed. Provide sample data in your question or in http://sqlfiddle.com/. Perhaps I'll be able to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have no matches because of your query.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id='$my_id'
```

The above will fetch only matching records.

Maybe you should alter your query or the line

```
 if (!empty($row['id']))
```

and check for another field that might be empty

Answer (score 0):

Your query explicitely filters out "non-matching" rows:

```sql
WHERE id = '$my_id' -- neither rows having "id != $my_id"
                    -- nor rows with empty "id" are fetched by this query
```

You probably want to remove the `WHERE` condition from your query, and test for `if($row['id'] === $my_id)` in your PHP loop.

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove "spaces" with trim:

```
if (!empty(trim($row['id']))) {
  echo 'Match Exists!';
}
```